# Comparison of Kaplan-Meier curves across ordered groups

Tags: survival, ordinal-data, kaplan-meier

I am familiar with the log-rank test for comparing multiple Kaplan-Meier curves, but I am looking for a test that will compare across ordered groups (an ordinal variable). A significant result from the log rank test indicates that at least one of the groups has a survival curve different than the others. I want a test where a significant test indicates that there is a monotonic trend in the survival curves over the levels of the ordinal grouping variable.

As a more concrete example, consider survival curves for cancer of different stages, and I want to show not just that the curves differ, but that the survival worsens as stage increases.

As a bonus, pointers to implementations of the algorithm in R would be appreciated.

---

Edit to address `@dardisco` comment:

When I tried to find a suitable test, I did find a reference so something that seemed appropriate in the documentation for MedCalc software at http://www.medcalc.org/manual/kaplan-meier.php. Two quotes that sounded like what I wanted from that are

> Options: Linear trend for factor levels: Allows testing for a linear trend across levels of the factor. It is appropriate if factor levels have a natural ordering (for example, factor codes represent doses applied to different groups). Kaplan-Meier assumes that the factor levels are equally spaced.

and

> Logrank test for trend: If more than two survival curves are compared, and there is a natural ordering of the groups, then MedCalc can also perform the logrank test for trend. This tests the probability that there is a trend in survival scores across the groups.

But no specific algorithm for this test is stated.

Comment: Did you have a particular method in mind and if so could you post a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `comp` in [survMisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survMisc/survMisc.pdf) may be close to what you're after. From the docs:

> **Tests for trend** are designed to detect ordered differences in survival curves.
> That is, for at least one group: $$S_1(t) \geq S_2(t) \geq ... \geq S_K(t) \quad t \leq \tau$$ where $\tau$ is the largest $t$ where all groups have at least one subject at risk. The null hypothesis is that $$S_1(t) = S_2(t) = ... = S_K(t) \quad t \leq \tau$$ Scores used to construct the test are typically $s = 1,2,...,K$, but may be given as a vector representing a numeric characteristic of the group.
> They are calculated by finding: $$Z_j(t_i) = \sum_{t_i \leq \tau} W(t_i)[e_{ji} - n_{ji} \frac{e_i}{n_i}], \quad j=1,2,...,K$$ The test statistic is: $$Z = \frac{ \sum_{j=1}^K s_jZ_j(\tau)}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^K \sum_{g=1}^K s_js_g \sigma_{jg}}}$$ where $\sigma$ is the the appropriate element in the variance-covariance matrix (see COV).
> If ordering is present, the statistic $Z$ will be greater than the upper $\alpha$-th percentile of a standard normal distribution.

For example:

```
library(survMisc)
data(larynx, package="KMsurv")
s4 <- survfit(Surv(time, delta) ~ stage, data=larynx)
comp(s4)
```

This will give *tests for trend* with various weights (as are used with the standard log-rank test):

```
$tests$trendTests
                                     Z       p
Log-rank                      3.718959 0.00010
Gehan-Breslow (mod~ Wilcoxon) 4.224765 0.00001
Tarone-Ware                   4.058010 0.00002
Peto-Peto                     4.129343 0.00002
Mod~ Peto-Peto (Andersen)     4.136319 0.00002
Trend F-H with p=1, q=1       2.396992 0.00827
```

The package has been changed slightly, and instead of `tests` or `trendtests`, use `tft`, which stands for... tests for trend. Furthermore, when using the `comp()` function, type it like this: `comp(ten(<whatever your survival-fit object is>))`.

Comment: From my initial read of the documentation, this seems like what I was looking for; I will investigate further.

Comment: For example: library(survMisc) data(larynx, package="KMsurv") s4 <- survfit(Surv(time, delta) ~ stage, data=larynx) comp(s4) $tests$trendTests Z p Log-rank -3.012202 0.99870 Gehan-Breslow (mod~ Wilcoxon) -3.324885 0.99956 Tarone-Ware -3.229613 0.99938 Peto-Peto -3.274397 0.99947 Mod~ Peto-Peto (Andersen) -3.278708 0.99948 Trend F-H with p=1, q=1 -2.037246 0.97919

Comment: hi, dardisco:I have run the same R code , but the results are different from yours

Comment: I see the same results you are now reporting here. I do not know why the results are different now, but that would be something to bring up with the package maintainer.

Comment: @Haitao Yang thank you for pointing this out, will try to correct ASAP